# Use username/password while pushing when ssh is already set up

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I was wondering if there is some way to force git use username/password (one time only) if ssh keys is already set up. I have setup ssh keys for one account but need to push to different repo not associated with that account. So is there any way to make git use username/password ignoring the ssh key which is already set up.

Comment: try clone using https protocal?

Comment: It is already cloned, do you mean pull?

Comment: `git remote set-url  origin https://...`